# In OR tools, more specifically in VRPTW, why start and end times for a time window should only be integers?

Tags: python, routes, or-tools

I am wondering why the start and end of time windows have to be integers, for example for a node who has 7am-10am window, it is (7, 10)? There could be case where a time window is between 7:30am-10:30am, which could be 7.5-11.5. Why the code doesn't allow decimal values for time windows?

When I have decimals, like (7.5-10.5) for the time window tuples, I got error saying, time windows are expected to be integers. While I can modify window to make it integers like (7-10), but that is not what I want if possible. How can we go about implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not count in minutes ? The solver is scale agnostic.

Comment: I think this is a good go-around.